# How do you move or remove the App Catalog site from a web app?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, web-application

I created an App Catalog site under the root of my web app (/), and I would like to move it to another path (e.g. `/sites/appcatalog`).

Does anyone know how to remove an existing App Catalog site, or move one to another path? Is it as simple as deleting the root site collection in the web app and recreating another App Catalog site for that web app? Or will that break the web app? Any PowerShell support for this activity?

This is a test environment I am working on, so no real data to worry about. I guess I could just delete and recreate the web app, but that would be a pain if this was a production environment with lots of content. Just looking for the most efficient way to accomplish this task, if it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Central Administration > Application Management > Delete Site Collection. Then select Change Site Collection from the dropdown and select the url of the app catalog. Once it populates the data, click delete.

Comment: You'll also need to use PowerShell to set the new URL since, (I think) even if the site doesn't exist anymore, the interface will have it locked to the old URL.

Comment: Someone reached out to me asking about the cmdlet I mentioned. It's: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj730454.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a new SiteCollection with PowerShell and change the URL to that SiteCollection:

```powershell
New-SPSite -Url https://domain.com/sites/AppCatalog -OwnerAlias "myuser" -Name "App Catalog site" -Template "APPCATALOG#0"
Update-SPAppCatalogConfiguration -Site:https://domain.com/sites/AppCatalog
iisreset
```